# Do we have dynamic code loading and execution support in Ballaerina?

Tags: ballerina, dynamic-loading, ballerina-swan-lake

I have a case where I use a Ballerina service to invoke ChatGPT and generate a Ballerina function. I want to execute this Ballerina function before returning the response.

How can I achieve this?. Do we have dynamic code loading and execution support?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `os:exec` to do this.
https://ballerina.io/spec/os/#4-operating-system-command-execution